# How to join 2 columns as one and order by date?

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-ce, union

I'm using SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0 and there are 2 tables called debit and credit as below.

**tbl_debit**

```
invoice | dealer | price| purchasedate
=========================================
  001   |  AAA   |  1000  | 2/9/2016 8:46:38 PM  
  002   |  AAA   |  1500  | 2/20/2016 8:46:38 PM
```

**tbl_credit**

```
 dealer | settlement| purchasedate
=========================================
  AAA   |    800    | 2/12/2016 8:46:38 PM  
  AAA   |    400    | 2/22/2016 8:46:38 PM
```

I want to create single table that should include 4 column..

```
 Invoice, Dealer, Amount, date
```

Amount should include both `settlement` from `tbl_credit` and `price` from `tbl_debit` and need to order by date.

I really appreciate if anyone can help me.

Comment: Show us **your efforts** so far!

Comment: You need to explain the logic for combining the tables.  What should the final results look like?

Comment: SELECT        amount, purchasedate
FROM            tbl_debit
UNION ALL
SELECT        amount, date
FROM            tbl_credit
ORDER BY purchasedate

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script to logically approach the problem based on the limited information presented to us:

```
SELECT A.invoice, A.dealer, A.amount, A.purchasedate
        FROM (SELECT A.invoice, A.dealer, A.price [amount], A.purchasedate
        WHERE tbl_debit A
        UNION
        SELECT ' ', B.dealer, B.settlement, B.purchasedate
        FROM tbl_credit B) A
        ORDER BY 4
```